# How to convert Normal purchase to Preauth message for VISA in VTS

Tags: visa-api

any one know how to change normal **purhcase auth** message to **preauth** in **VTS**?
is it only DE25?

Comment: According to VISA technical specification there is no such element to indicate that as i checked. but master card have.